# How do I solve this middle number problem?

Tags: c++, c, loops, if-statement

Write a program where the user inputs 3 float numbers and the program checks which is medium size number. Example : `a = 1.5`, `b = 7.8`, and `c = 3.0` and output should be `c`.
This is what I've tried and it worked for one case, but I'm still doing too much spaghetti code and I'm still learning how to write code efficiently.
My code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    float a, b, c;

    scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);

    if(a < b && c < a)
        printf("%.1f", a);
    else if(b < a && b > c)
        printf("%.1f", b);
    else if(c > a && c < b)
        printf("%.1f", c);
    else
    {
        printf("not good"); //I wrote this part to check if the code is good
    }




    return 0;
}
```

I'm still trying to get the hang of the `if` loops and I was just confused with this problem. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: please choose one language. Maybe your code is one of the (rare) cases that is valid C code and valid C++ code, but the slightest modification can change that

Comment: more on-topic: `if` and loops are two different things. What specifically is confusing you? If you have working code and want to get a review then https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ is the better place to ask, because asking for "any suggestions" is in danger of getting closed as too broad/opinion based here

Comment: Here's a hint: There are 2 ways for `a` to be the middle number. c < a < b or b < a < c. Your code only considers the first case. Also you need to consider the case where a, b or c are equal to each other.

Comment: What should this program output if two of the numbers are equal or all three are equal? It's also valid to say, "assume that will never happen", but if that's the case please put that limitation in your question.

Answer (score 1):

think of like, if a is medium , then b is medium, then c is medium. Check if that hepls!

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){

float a, b, c;

scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);

if((a > b && a < c) || (a > c && a < b) ) 
    printf("%.1f", a);
else if((b > a && b < c) || (b > c && b < a))
    printf("%.1f", b);
else if((c > a && c < b) || (c > b && c < a))
    printf("%.1f", c);
else
{
    printf("not good"); //I wrote this part to check if the code is good
}




return 0;
```

}

Comment: Thanks, it helped, but I'm still new to c++ so what does | | mean? It seems I never used that.

Comment: `||` means 'or'. But this solution is overly complex.

Comment: So what happens, if `a == b == c`?

Answer (score 0):

If you can use C++:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main(){
    float a, b, c;

    scanf("%f %f %f", &a, &b, &c);

    // Put them in a vector. Could use array, but vector more flexible
    vector<float> vals = {a,b,c};

    // Sort in numerical order
    sort (vals.begin(),vals.end());

    // Display the middle one
    printf("%.1f", vals[1]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: if you create a vector with 3 elements upfront (why not a `std::array`?) then you dont need `a`,`b` and `c` but you can store user input directly in the vector

Comment: As I say, a vector is more flexible in that the number of items we find the middle on of can be determined at runtime.

Comment: The input of the numbers is not the crux of the question, so I felt it better not to cause distraction by changing that.

Comment: flexibility that is not needed just opens the door to mistakes. In the code there can only be 3 elements. Even if you change the code to use 4, then still the number of elements is known at compile time, just saying...

Comment: `scanf` is C++  ??

Comment: It's valid in C++. I wouldn't use it, but that wasn't the crux of the question.